# Custome prefix for sequence - OdooV14

Tags: boolean, odoo, sequence, prefix, quotations

I'm trying to change the prefix of quotation's sequence in Odoo.
I want that the prefix change by a boolean but i don't have any result.

Here is my code :

```
class prefix_change(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'

prefix_choice = fields.Boolean(string="Set to OL", default=False)


def _get_sequence(self, xml_id='quotation.seq'):

    user = self.env.user
    sequence = self.env['ir.sequence'].with_company(user.company_id).next_by_code(xml_id)

    if not sequence:
        return _('New')
    try:
        prefix, suffix = sequence.split('-')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(repr(e))
        return _('New')

    if not self.prefix_choice :
        prefix = "BE"
    else:
        prefix = "OL"

    return "%s-%s-%s" % (prefix, suffix)
```

Thanks by advance....

Comment: You can use create and write method in order to change the name of SO. Please let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: Indeed, I hesitated a lot, but I don't know if this is appropriate because I want the prefix to change depending on the boolean (checked = true and the prefix = OL AND unchecked = false and the prefix = BE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer W.R.T create and write call:

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    res = super(prefix_change, self).create(values)
    name = res.name
    if res.prefix_choice:
        name = res.name.replace('SO', 'OL')
    else:
        name = res.name.replace('SO', 'BE')

    res.name = name
    return res


def write(self, values):
    res = super(prefix_change, self).write(values)
    if 'prefix_choice' in values and values.get('prefix_choice'):
        #update code accordingly if needed
        if 'BE' in self.name:
            self.name = self.name.replace('BE', 'OL')
    if 'prefix_choice' in values and not values.get('prefix_choice'):
        if 'OL' in self.name:
            self.name = self.name.replace('OL', 'BE')


    return res
```

Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help first of all! In the write function, under "if 'prefix_choice' in values:" I'm supposed to replace the prefix in case of an update?

Comment: Yes but in write before replacing the prefix you have to check if string contains 'BE' or 'OL'.

Comment: Oh yes sure ! I tried for the create function, but it's not working, it's like if when I press create, the name is not yet generated and therefore it cannot replace the characters

Comment: Action will take place after saving the record.

Comment: I've update my answer for write method too.

Comment: Your code looks good but it seems like not working for the create method, i tried it and i still got no result

Comment: Use logger or print in order to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Ok it works now, i was returning the name only my bad